# how can I add values into an array without erasing previous values in array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I  created array using `JavaScript` for android phone-gap and push index value of link into an  array while clicking the particular link in dynamic list.Again I run that application and click the other link , current value`(ie.,clicked link -indexvalue(I think - it each time create a new array))` is stored in array.

how to maintain previous values in array each time I will run that application and also how to add current value into the same array?

My code is:

```
 var arr1=new Array();
  $(".sidemenu li ").click(function() {        
        var index = $('li').index(this); 
        saveIndex(index);
    });
 function saveIndex(index) {

 alert(index);
 arr1.push(index);
 window.localStorage.setItem("key",JSON.stringify(arr1));

  var arr = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("key"));
  alert(arr);

 }
```

please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you declare the array index as a global variable..

Comment: show some code snippet. hard to tell what youre trying to do.

Comment: Do you want to save the array for the users session or everytime the user logs in ?

Comment: mm..it seems global variable would solve your problem.. just declare array globally, and then do a push when you insert.stuff in it wont be overwritten.

Comment: @BennyTjia I think the OP needs to save the data between sessions - ie a cookie

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I declared array as global variable.and then push value into an array.I want to each time i run that application array contain previous values and also it will store current value.how to do that? please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
var my_array = [];

//your code on click
my_array.push(my_value);
```

Comment: This is not a question on how to add values to an array - he wants to keep the array everytime the user opens the page

Comment: now i see it :D
then, you should create that array dinamically with php using stored values in mysql database. the values would be stored using ajax

Comment: yes I want to keep the array(contain previos value) every time user open page and also store current value in that array.I created application in android phonegap.So I only use javascript/jquery.Please guide me

Comment: you have 2 options: database or session. database is permanent, session is until user leaves the app

Comment: how to use database ? please give some example using javascript or jquery.Because I use array values for displaying already clicked link in different color and unvisited link in differrent color for each time I run that application.so that only I ask how to maintain previous and current value in array. please guide me.

Comment: does your users need to login in order to use the map? if they don't, it's pretty hard to keep track of their progress. maybe you can asign a unique id into a cookie and syncronize that with the database, but that's just dirty work. if they delete the cookies, their work is lost.